# getDefaultProps and getInitialState not working as expected

Tags: reactjs

I am a beginner in reactjs. I was trying some of the examples. In the following is a program I am working on, but getDefaultProps and getInitialState are not working as expected.

getDefaultProps does not return the default name when I haven't specified any name prop for the Greeter component. 
When I specify getInitialState, my form doesn't get displayed.

```
var Greeter = React.createClass({
  getDefaultProps: function() {
    console.log(this.props);
    return 
    {
      name: "React";
    }
  },
  getInitialState: function() {
    return 
    {
      name: this.props.name;
    }
  },
  onButtonClick: function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var name = this.refs.name.value;
    this.setState({
      name: name
    });

    //alert(name);
  },
  render: function() {
    var name = this.state.name;
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Hi {name}</h1>
        <p>This is from the react component</p>

        <form onSubmit={this.onButtonClick}>
          <input type="text" ref="name" />
          <button>Set Name</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
});

var name = "Lmntrix";

ReactDOM.render(<Greeter name={name} />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You had your objects returned on a new line, which I think caused javascript to return `undefined`:

```
getDefaultProps: function ()
{
    console.log(this.props);
    return
    {
        name:"React"
    };
},
getInitialState: function()
{
    return
    {
        name: this.props.name;
    }
},
```

When I coppied that code to [prettier](https://prettier.io/playground/#N4Igxg9gdgLgprEAuEA3AhgJwAQHFNxzw4C82ASnOmDAHRgHrwDCANugM4cAUwAOlADmRACJwAZugCurGAAVMEAA4ck2cVKg0AltGzcAlAP5RsZ7JCgcIrOLVYRB3GAAttHWksUqDAbgHm2AQwUphQAeYmgYFQ6AC2cEh8IJTUMMkRZgC+-lBZADQCwjAAklDaMNrorADKMEyJ6po60IbGmUFEoeGmkR0x8Y2u7p7eHrEJuYFZAgUC0ABCUjAw0GzaYADWSBpala1wRlBR5nZecKgIMGKSMjCGuR0YOBNw2GTDHgTi44O0GKwpHApuZPrQOEQ6g1uP0+r1otFXtg1K9YdkOn4BB0APTY6pwTD3V6YvKFKAEKAAEwJal2LVMbWOTyw2CRHzcHg49XgtFeILMwW6MPh2AAPJTtKgAHxosUuACMUoAEtpsMBXllRdiFTKRYFRUopQAVDnYdzqRRxbCuN6MGgWCBxJTQK5aw1YvXmUXiCCYK3QGpSABGcQqJGAYMWy1WUHWWyyuoRCNF2igSmW1oAnko4CRkvAAB7pECdcR5kCokDYxNJ-VB6PQKU1IjYABygy19ZWjdlWp9fprZi1EulGNyMzyJI9z1Zg3e2GSABk4rBMNoC8lHlBUjQRAB5ACytAp1MwwtF+EIxFnCXDGurZMpEDAUgSsFoxQAorY3zAFpmSkpGEQHQJQlGSI4-BAfIQGUfYrGQUAsEUAB3OQsAQDhkBA1AIG0SloJAINMGoTZISUahU0EZAYEwIEYNTCFCQUdBBDidBkEkVgIRggArDgCwWEitkhQZF1TOBOOqHiQAozAmOwoN0CDTMHCgQivFTGAAHV8NcZAAA4AAYYK8CAIW0kilGw84mMuQiCAARykbQCBYtiOJ2aS4BgiFQxouifJADgqNsABFKQIHgKTuKC+og10yl9KQAAmGDaPQbRWCo5hHXY7CoBdQipAhI1lKwrzYqyLIgA) it automatically added semicolons which proves my point:

```
  getDefaultProps: function() {
    console.log(this.props);
    return;
    {
      name: "React";
    }
  },
  getInitialState: function() {
    return;
    {
      name: this.props.name;
    }
  },
```

So to fix that try:

```
  getDefaultProps: function() {
    console.log(this.props);
    return {
      name: "React";
    }
  },
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      name: this.props.name;
    }
  },
```

Comment: I don't think that spacing should matter for the output. But as you were so confident with that, I tried that too but it didn't work for me.

Comment: @AkshvirSoni that may not solve it but it is certainly an issue too. See https://repl.it/repls/TenderYouthfulCopyleft

Comment: Thanks @Tomasz, got your point. but I don't think that is the case with my code, as rectifying that too doesn't get me the desired output.